How to set direction for gt::data_color to all table
I am asking about gt:: package, mainly the data_color() function, and the direction argument.
My data contains numeric values. Here is a reproducible example:
require(gt)
n <- 5
set.seed(23)
data.frame(
  product_name = sample(LETTERS,n),
  performance_1 = rnorm(n,-1,1),
  performance_2 = runif(n,-1,1),
  performance_3 = runif(n,-1,1),
  performance_4 = rnorm(n,0,1)
) |>
  gt::gt() |>
  data_color(
    columns = contains("performance"),
    direction = "row", # I want the direction to be from all table, not just row/column
    fn = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("tomato","gold","green4"),
      domain = NULL
    )
  )


My question: The direction argument takes either rows or columns. Can I manipulate this argument so the coloring will be computed according to all numeric values in the table?
Instead of set.seed you can also reproduce my code using dput
structure(list(product_name = c("X", "S", "H", "K", "G"), performance_1 = c(-0.00339489316645392, 
0.107490487448087, -1.27808628285053, 0.0192054876250842, -0.954562821242861
), performance_2 = c(0.884923394303769, 0.256039271131158, 0.172795631922781, 
-0.450518076308072, -0.70468607544899), performance_3 = c(0.60282064601779, 
-0.227180351037532, 0.640901388134807, 0.36987454816699, 0.766778532415628
), performance_4 = c(-1.21637642702189, 0.30813689628972, -0.52017831497405, 
-0.442313800737427, -0.599312811975944)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

data_color() documentation on direction:

Color computation direction
⁠singl-kw:[column|row]⁠ // default: "column"
Should the color computations be performed column-wise or row-wise? By
default this is set with the "column" keyword and colors will be
applied down columns. The alternative option with the "row" keyword
ensures that the color mapping works across rows.

Regards

From the docs I don't see any default option to achieve that. But I might be wrong.
Anyway, one option to achieve your desired result would be to use the domain= argument:
library(gt)

range_performance <- dat |> 
  dplyr::select(contains("performance")) |> 
  unlist() |> 
  range()

dat |>
  gt::gt() |>
  data_color(
    columns = contains("performance"),
    fn = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = c("tomato", "gold", "green4"),
      domain = range_performance
    )
  )



Thanks! I just realised it makes it possible to set quantile coloring using col_quantile. what a great package (wish they'd add direction = 'all' though)
